# How can multiple layout dynamically in android?

Tags: android, layout

I wanna set multiple layout dynamically one by one. how may i do this i used way but it shows only one layout with one textview.and i wanna set layout according to iteration of my loop. i used this code.

```
public class Show extends Activity
{
    Context context=null;
    TextView textView=null,textView1=null,textView2=null;
    LinearLayout linearLayout1=null;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearlayoutParam=null;
    protected void  onCreate(Bundle state)
    {
         super.onCreate(state);
          context=getApplicationContext();
          int top=0;
          for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
          {
              textView=new TextView(context);
              textView.setId(i);
              textView.setText("Hii Priyank");
              textView.setMinimumHeight(top);
              textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
              linearLayout1=new LinearLayout(context);
              linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
              linearLayout1.setId(i);
              linearlayoutParam=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              linearlayoutParam.setMargins(10, top, 10, 10);
              linearLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
              top=top+10;

             linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(linearlayoutParam);
             LayoutInflater layoutinflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              linearLayout1.addView(textView, linearlayoutParam);
              System.out.println(i);

          }
          setContentView(linearLayout1,linearlayoutParam);

}
```

It show this result only but i wanna set multiple.[image]

it show this result only.

Comment: You are creating a new linearlayout every loop, create t before the for loop and add th textview in the loop

Answer (score 1):

write `linearLayout1=new LinearLayout(context);` before `for` loop, and remove this from loop

edit

```
public class Show extends Activity
{
    Context context=null;
    TextView textView=null;
    LinearLayout linearLayout1=null;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearlayoutParam=null;
    protected void  onCreate(Bundle state)
    {
         super.onCreate(state);
         context=this;
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams rootlayoutParam=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         LinearLayout rootLayout=new LinearLayout(context);
         rootLayout.setLayoutParams(rootlayoutParam);
         rootLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
         int top=0;
          for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
          {
              textView=new TextView(context);
              textView.setId(i);
              textView.setText("Hii Priyank");
              textView.setMinimumHeight(top);
              textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
              linearLayout1=new LinearLayout(context);
              linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
              linearLayout1.setId(i);
              linearlayoutParam=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
              linearlayoutParam.setMargins(10, top, 10, 10);
              linearLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
              top=top+10;

             linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(linearlayoutParam);
             LayoutInflater layoutinflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             linearLayout1.addView(textView, linearlayoutParam);
             rootLayout.addView(linearLayout1);
             System.out.println(i);

          }

          setContentView(rootLayout);

}
}
```

Comment: every time i wanna set new layout so i put in loop

Comment: if you set new layout in loop,every iteration of loop clear the old value in  layout, so after loop layout have only value of last iteration of loop

Answer (score 1):

Create a `LinearLayout` in your activity xml file. then do

```
setContentView(R.layout.linear_layout_xml);
```

Find the LinearLayout in the activity class as

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_id);
```

Then at the end of each loop use this

```
ll.addView(viewToBeAdded);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
View linearLayout =  new LinearLayout(context);

     for(int i=0;i<=3;i++)
              {
            TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
            valueTV.setText("hallo hallo");
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);

            valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);

            ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(valueTV);
    }
```

Comment: check it params.setMargins(10,10,10,10); added in above code

Answer (score 0):

```
Context context = null;
TextView textView = null, textView1 = null, textView2 = null;
LinearLayout linearLayout1 = null;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams linearlayoutParam = null;

protected void onCreate(Bundle state) {
    super.onCreate(state);
    context = getApplicationContext();
    int top = 0;
    LinearLayout rootView = new LinearLayout(context);
    rootView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams rooParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        textView = new TextView(context);
        textView.setId(i);
        textView.setText("Hii Priyank");
        textView.setMinimumHeight(top);
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        linearLayout1 = new LinearLayout(context);
        linearLayout1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linearLayout1.setId(i);
        linearlayoutParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        linearlayoutParam.setMargins(10, top, 10, 10);
        linearLayout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        top = top + 10;

        linearLayout1.setLayoutParams(linearlayoutParam);
        LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        linearLayout1.addView(textView, linearlayoutParam);
        rootView.addView(linearLayout1);
        System.out.println(i);

    }
    setContentView(rootView, linearlayoutParam);

}
```